# Different server for each country/domain but the same admin

Tags: database, multistore, language, hosting

I need to put front end for each country to own domain and server. But admin should be the same for all countries. Is possible to accomplish that?

Comment: What do you mean by putting FEs to different servers?

Comment: Each local site should have IP of local country due SEO. That is why new host for each country. I know that this may not be relevant for SEO at all, but my client want that...

Comment: Why not just route all those IPs to single server?

Comment: I didn't know that is possible. Please write couple of words more about it so I will know what to google. tnx

Comment: bThis is actually a business problem. Server location is one of many SEO factors, but bascially will have limited effect. If you have country tlds (.com/.co.uk) in English it will be picked up, however if you have .fr/.de then Google expects local language content. Having a server in the US is perfectly fine, we have used specialist hosting and seen sites listed first page Google next to Amazon & eBay in the UK, it made no differece if the other factors are there. You can technically do it as suggested, but ROI is negative - too many qualitative factors - better to concentrate on other things.

Answer (score 0):

1. As Tim suggested, you could either have different reverse-proxies with the different IPs and then proxy your server through all of them. This may solve your problem but adds (a lot?) of latency to your request - but you could think about using varnish as reverse proxy, so you can cache most of the stuff on your country-machines.
2. Second idea (which is as bad as the first one) is to have one database server which is not at the same data center as your server (because every server is in one country and they all share one database server). Adds a lot of latency too, you have to secure the connection via SSL or VPN, a lot of work, no advantage (if you ask me)
3. The third idea is to just split the whole installation on different servers, database included. But then you have to maintain N installations, which is no problem, if you automation, import and export works well.

If this is not the case you should really think about this. What your clients wants brings a lot of problems on process level, which makes things quite expensive.